# Riak sibling creation in erlang

Tags: erlang, riak, siblings

Suppose two processes execute the same write command at the same time to RIAK with same bucket and same key (might be addressing two different RIAK nodes) with allow_mult true and the key is definitely new in the bucket:
{ok, WrittenObject} = riakc_pb_socket:put(Pid, Obj, [return_body])

Can it happen that both processes get WrittenObject back where riakc_obj:value_count(WrittenObject) is greater than 1, or definitely one process will have it as 1 and the other gets the value of 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what is already stored at the key, and what vclock is included with each put request, the value count may be 1,2 or 3.  Assuming no partition event (i.e. non-failure case), each put will be coordinated by one of the primary vnodes in the key's preflist, and if the vclock contained in the object being stored does not dominate the one already present, both values will be stored.  Even if both requests are made nearly simultaneously, which is processed first, and which if not both see a sibling will be a race.

Edit:
If the `allow_mult` property on the bucket is set to false, Riak will select a single value to return based on the `X-Riak-Last-Modified` and `X-Riak-Deleted` entries in metadata.  This means that the value you put may not be the value returned.

Only if `allow_mult` is true will you see more than one value returned.

Comment: Thanks! So if the key is new and no vclocks were used in neither put, the request of the node processed first will get 1, and the other will get 2 as the first node request was processed already and the object was already stored. So it cannot happen, that two replicas gets cross written, ie. the same object written twice will be stored on two different nodes first, than the replica of the object is stored on the other node and at the time of the replica, each write finds the object on the other node to write, right?This means the put is an atomic operation regardless of the number of replicas.

Comment: Neither operation can be guaranteed to 'process first' since each one will be processed by several vnodes.  It is entirely possible that request 1 will be processed first on one vnode, while request 2 is processed first on another, resulting in both requests seeing siblings.

Comment: There is no need for guarantee. It was a simple question. As the two process theoretically executed at the same time, I meant the first that has it's request written first by RIAK. The two requests are identical. The question was about the possibility to have 2 siblings for both process. So sorry but it is still unclear. You said, both process can get siblings back. If this is the case, it means the replicas were cross written. Can we define, how the siblings metadata will look like in terms of last_written? Again, only two process lives and write the same object. No failures, but replicas.

Comment: This piqued my interest, so I looked through the source code a bit.  The put process calls the [reconcile function](https://github.com/basho/riak_kv/blob/1.4.8/src/riak_object.erl#L173).  So if you want just one object returned, and you want it to be the one with the most recent modification time, just set `allow_mult` to false.

Comment: Thanks Joe. Unfortunately I would like to have the least recent one and this is why my question was raised. I also thought a bit last night and came to a conclusion that I need to find the sibling with the smallest last_mod value and write it back. For this, I also needed to store the Pid of the process so it would be the only one who update the object back and the other process just leave it. I prepared, that both process can get back siblings, althought it means cross writing the object so it is still not clear for me.

Comment: Digging deeper, the question is, how RIAK handles the write command? Lets call them A and B and the processes named as such as well. Object A and B are identical. When the two writes get to the node responsible for the vnode, are those serialized or not. If not (supposing SMP), it can happen that the first replica of A is written to the node and at the same time the second replica of B is written to another node. In the next step, on the other way around, but in this case, what happens with the vector clocks? Both replicas will have inconsistent vclock. And how would it be reconciled later on?

Comment: The write process in Riak, when there are no node/network failures works like this:

Comment: The client sends a put request to whichever node it is connected, if that node does not own one of the n_val replicas in which the key should be stored, it forwards the request to one of them, selected randomly.  The node that receives that request is the coordinating node.  It first stores the object locally to establish the vclock, then sends it to the other replicas.  The response to the client is sent after `w` is satisfied.  It is likely the 2 put requests may be coordinated by different nodes, so if the 2nd does the local put before the 1st finishes replicating, both could see siblings.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand this. The only open question for me is about the vclock. If the above happens (2 siblings for both processes) the vclocks seems to be different in the replicas (in my theory) as they were cross written. So in the next read, I will get a vclock, reconcile, select the sibling make a put. But this vclock will be matching with only on one replica. What will happen with the other? How does RIAK handle this?

Comment: The replicas will all contain a sibling object that contains both values, when you resolve the siblings to a single value, they will all be updated.